# Inserting multiple Attributes into an XML Element. LINQ SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am able to get my results, but seems like there is a better way to do it.

```
        doc.Element("XML").SetAttributeValue("Type", "ListBuilder");
        doc.Element("XML")
           .Element("Order").SetAttributeValue("No", 425654);
        doc.Element("XML")
           .Element("Order").SetAttributeValue("DispDate", today);
        doc.Element("XML")
           .Element("Order").SetAttributeValue("Basket", 3536);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do the same by adding `XAttribute` items to the elements.  This leaves you with more options in general as these could be dynamically generated if you needed to.

```
doc.Element("XML").Add(new XAttribute("Type", "ListBuilder"));
doc.Element("XML").Element("Order").Add(new[]
{
    new XAttribute("No", 425654),
    new XAttribute("DispDate", today),
    new XAttribute("Basket", 3536),
});
```

Comment: I completely forgot with [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345077(v=vs.110).aspx) method you can add any kind of content. I totally support this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe saving your element references in variables to not search them every time you need to add an attribute to them:

```
var xml= doc.Element("XML");
xml.SetAttributeValue("Type", "ListBuilder");

var order=xml.Element("Order");
order.SetAttributeValue("No", 425654);
//...
```

Comment: That is certainly better than what I had. Thank you